# How to read the content from file line by line?

Tags: android

How to read the content from file line by line?
I can get the content, but the content are in the same line, how can I get the content line by line ?

```
    FileInputStream fileIn =null;
        BufferedInputStream bufFileIn=null;

        try{
            fileIn = openFileInput("AlbumEdit.txt");
            bufFileIn = new BufferedInputStream(fileIn);
            byte[] bufBytes = new byte[20];
            medtplay.setText("");
            do{
                int c = bufFileIn.read(bufBytes);
                if(c==-1)break;
                else medtplay.append(new String(bufBytes),0,c);

            } while (true);
            bufFileIn.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Buddy there a 100 answer on this site...please do some home work

Comment: I'm sorry, but I tried many answer and didn't work.. so I ask for help

Comment: After every line (i.e when reader.hasNext() will return true if there is another line below to read) insert a \n before doing append so the content that are all seems to coming in one line will separated by a line separator.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
 BufferedReader reader;

try{
final InputStream file = getAssets().open("text.txt");
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));
String line = reader.readLine();
while(line != null){

    line = reader.readLine();
}
} catch(IOException ioe){
ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: no its work fine ,,,any error occur? if yes means tell the error